# Can the domain of Poincaré–Miranda theorem be unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove the existence of the solution of a function.
$$
f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n
$$

- $x_i \to -\infty$, then $f_i(X)=-\infty$
- $x_i \to \infty$, then $f_i(X)=a$ finite positive constant

Poincaré–Miranda theorem requires the domain is closed. Does the theorem also exist when the domain is open?

Comment: Please put more details into the question. Not everyone is immediately aware that Poincaré–Miranda is a multidimensional generalization of the intermediate value theorem to some unit cube.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=T(u)$, $x_i=\tan u_i$ and $g_i(u)=\arctan(f_i(T(u)))$. Then you are back to the finite/bounded case mapping $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]^n$ into itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have one more question. If that "$x_i \to \infinity$ then $f_i(X)=a$" only holds when $x_{-i}$s are much smaller than $x_i$, can I also prove the existence?